# Move a square through a subview

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibezierpath, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I'm new in Swift. 
I'm trying to move a square with the gesture Recognizer in swift 3, but I don't know how to do it.. I want to make it with UISwipeGestureRecognizer, because later the square it would be use as the head of a Snake :)

Here it's the code:

```
@IBAction func Start(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.StartTheGame()
}

@IBOutlet var StartGame: UIButton!



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // set container frame and add to the screen
    self.container.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 20, width: 390, height: 740)
    self.view.addSubview(container)
    self.container.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    self.container.addSubview(StartGame)

    let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleGesture))
    swipeLeft.direction = .left
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)
    let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleGesture))
    swipeRight.direction = .right
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)
    let swipeUp = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleGesture))
    swipeUp.direction = .up
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)
    let swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleGesture))
    swipeDown.direction = .down
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)
}

func handleGesture(gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
    if gesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.right {
        print("Swipe Right")
    }
    else if gesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.left {
        print("Swipe Left")
    }
    else if gesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.up {
        print("Swipe Up")
    }
    else if gesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.down {
        print("Swipe Down")
    }
}

func StartTheGame() {
self.StartGame!.isHidden = true
    let rect = Draw(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 170, y: 300), size: CGSize(width: 40, height: 40)))
    self.container.addSubview(rect)
}
```

Here it's the class draw:

```
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let h = rect.height
        let w = rect.width
        UIColor.yellow.set()
        let rect = CGRect(x: (w * 0.25),y: (h * 0.25),width: (w * 0.5),height: (h * 0.5))
        let bpath:UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(rect: rect)
        bpath.fill()
        //UIBezierPath(rect: rect).fill()
        NSLog("drawRect has updated the view")

    }

}
```

`

Comment: You want a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, not a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`, as the former tracks continuous finger movement, and the latter is just for quick swipes in one direction.

Comment: `Draw` is (almost always) a verb, and thus a _terrible_ name for a class. And don't you want the gesture to be attached to the view that's being moved, not the container view?

Comment: But I used UISWipeGestureRecognizer becouse I want a quick swipe, to change the direction for the snake (snake game - move up, down, left, right, just with one touch in the screen), that's why i use Swipe.

Comment: and yes, it's ok also to attached to the view, not the container.. i just want to trying how to make it also in a subview.

But I don't know how to make move to the square, give it new values a and, draw the head of the snake in the next place

Answer (score 0):

Following up on our comments, you need to do two things: add `@objc` your `handleGesture()` function so that it can be used in a selector, and make sure that your selector specifies the correct signature, which is `handleGesture(:)` because it takes a single argument.